# Spring JDBC store SchedulerFactoryBean can't trigger stored trigger manually

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a clustered Quartz (version 2.1.6) scheduler that seems to work fine when deployed to a websphere cluster. The scheduler is created by Spring (version 3.1.3_RELEASE).

```
<bean id="scheduler-JDBC" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" abstract="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory" />
    </property>
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>            
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">${org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cronScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" parent="scheduler-${scheduler:RAM}" depends-on="quartzDatabaseInitializer">
    <property name="startupDelay" value="10" />
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerStats" />             
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The trigger and the job is stored in the database. The job is created with job_name="serverStatsJob" and job_group="DEFAULT"
The trigger is executing every 20 min.
How do I trigger the job manually?

I have tried

```
StdScheduler cronScheduler = (StdScheduler)springContext.getBean("cronScheduler");
cronScheduler.triggerJob(new JobKey("serverStatsJob", "DEFAULT"));
```

which works if I use a RAM store instead of JDBC

I have also tried creating a new trigger with the stored job

```
Trigger trigger1 = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("serverStatsJobTrigger", "userRequested")
.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
.withRepeatCount(0))
.startNow()
.forJob(new JobKey("serverStatsJob", "DEFAULT"))
.build();
cronScheduler.scheduleJob(trigger1);
```

But it doesn't work either.
Could someone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself.
The scheduler isn't executing in a transaction correctly.

I added a `<tx:advice>` for the scheduler and now it works.

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="quartzSchedulerPointcut" expression="execution(* org.quartz.Scheduler.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="quartzSchedulerAdvice" pointcut-ref="quartzSchedulerPointcut" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="quartzSchedulerAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```